# Laravel Passing multi-dimentional array data to the server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dynamically generated form in tabular format in HTML, that I want to send and process on server. I am using Laravel but help in PHP will also be appreciated.

Here is the table, for clarity, I removed the unnecessary details

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Address 2</td>
    <td><label ><input name="servLabels[0][]" value="81F2D864-358E8A74F26D~A2" checked="" type="checkbox"> A 2 </label> </td>
    <td><label ><input name="servLabels[0][]" value="81F2D864-358E8A74F26D~M2~T-ASC-15" checked="" type="checkbox"> M 2 </label></td>
    <td><label ><input name="servLabels[0][]" value="81F2D864-358E8A74F26D~C2~T-ASC-29" checked="" type="checkbox"> C 2 </label></td>
    <td><label ><input name="servLabels[0][]" value="81F2D864-358E8A74F26D~P2~T-ASC-36" checked="" type="checkbox"> P 2 </label></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td>Address 1</td>
    <td><label><input name="servLabels[1][]" value="83209090-FF86B037CA41~A1" checked="" type="checkbox">A 1</label></td>
    <td><label><input name="servLabels[1][]" value="83209090-FF86B037CA41~M1~T-ASC-15" checked="" type="checkbox"> M 1 </label></td>
    <td><label><input name="servLabels[1][]" value="83209090-FF86B037CA41~C1~T-ASC-29" checked="" type="checkbox"> C 1 </label></td>
    <td><label><input name="servLabels[1][]" value="83209090-FF86B037CA41~P1~T-ASC-36" checked="" type="checkbox"> P 1 </label></td>
</tr>
```

On server, first we want to check, if checkbox was checked?
If it was checked, split the value of that checkbox by ~ sign into three.

Can anyone suggest please, how to iterate through this array? and if checkbox was checked, split the values into three? only the PHP part.

Comment: Do you have check/uncheck type of check box and you want to pass value to server ?

Comment: Yes, On each row of the table,  I have 4 check boxes.

Comment: So, You want to get input at server side like `0110`, `1100` ?

Comment: If a checkbox was checked, first we want its value (e.g 81F2D864-358E8A74F26D~M2~T-ASC-15 )

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something like ``$foo = $request->get('servLabels') ?? [];`` should get you all contents of the servLabels array or an empty array if ``..get('servLabels')`` is NULL depending on your PHP version. Might be obvious but the inputs should be placed inside a form

Comment: What's your progress so far ?

Comment: Not much, it is sending the data to the server. only the values of the check boxes exists that were checked in array.